# Bootstrap Notification Alerts

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter project to manage letter details. Then I need to notify no of urgent letters in the menu bar as a Bootstrap notification to each subject users. Urgent letters denoted by 2 (Two) in the classification column.

## Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $meta=array(
            'UrgentLetters'=>$this->Welcome_Model->getUrgentLetters()           
            );

        $this->load->view('header',$meta);
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

## Model

```
function getUrgentLetters()
    {
        $subject = $this->session->userdata('subject_id');          
        
        $this->db->select("letter_subject.subject_name AS subjects, count(letter_id) AS no_of_urgent");
        $this->db->from('letter_letter');
        $this->db->join('letter_subject', 'letter_subject.subject_id=letter_letter.subject');        
        $this->db->where('letter_letter.status=1 and letter_letter.classification=2');
        
        $this->db->group_by('subject_name');
        if ($subject && $subject !=100)
           $this->db->where('letter_letter.subject', $subject);

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q;
        }   
    }
```

## View

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                        
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-info"><?= count($UrgentLetters) ?></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 940px">
                            <li class="header">You have <?= count($UrgentLetters)?> Urgent Letters</li>
                            <li>
                                <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <table style="width: 100%">
                                        <thead style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                                        <tr style="width: 100%">
                                            <th style="width: 40%;padding-left: 2%;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 5px">Subject Name</th>
                                            <th style="width: 40%;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 5px">Letter Count</th>
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach ($UrgentLetters as $UrgentLetterss){
                                        $subjects=$UrgentLetterss->subjects;
                                        $no_of_urgent = $UrgentLetterss->no_of_urgent;                                     

                                        
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 45%;padding-left: 2%'>$subjects</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 45%'>$no_of_urgent->desc</td>";
                                       
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

All the sections are working fine. But the following error encountered.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: PDO::$subjects

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 111
```

What may be the reason ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: could you show the output of `echo '<pre>';print_r($meta)`, please

Comment: @  Vickel. What is the place I should insert  echo '<pre>';print_r($meta) ?

Comment: @ Vickel. The output is, Array
(
    [UrgentLetters] => 
)

Comment: @ Vickel. The new output is Array
(
    [UrgentLetters] => 1
). I think this is the no of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing to return a query result like

```
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
  return $q->result();
}
```

right now you just send a CI_DB_mysqli_result Object and therefor you get the error message in your view.

see [Generating Query Results()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)